# Erro ao reconhecer WebDriverWait

Tags: visual-studio, selenium-webdriver

Estou realizando um teste unitário em C# com *Selenium* *WebDriver* e ao tentar digitar o código *WebDriverWait* o mesmo não é encontrado.

Estou usando os namespaces abaixo e mesmo assim não reconhece.

```
OpenQA.Selenium;
OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
System.Threading;
Selenium.WebDriver.WaitExtensions;
OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
```

[image: Como apresenta no Visual Studio]

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver pessoal. Importei manualmente a dll do OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI e resolveu. Baixando pelo Nuget não deu certo.